In Tigergraph, what is the formatting for a Vertex to have several lines of text?
I have have a csv file.  I am trying to have several lines of text in each cell.
for example:  in the first cell of the csv file, I have
John Smith,
Aviator Supervisor,
L3

Each cell in the first column would contain entries like the above example.
Is this possible to do in TigerGraph?  If so, what is the proper formatting in the csv file for a cell that has multiple lines of text?
Also, when I create the vertex and load the file, are there any configurations that need to be done?
Thank you greatly for your help.
Spencer Neal
I have tried, separating the lines of text with a common and putting each text on a new line.
I have also tried to load multiple CSV files and relate the columns to the Vertex.

You should try using TigerGraph's FLATTEN function along with a TEMP_TABLE to load your data. If you check the "data load" tab in the documentation, you'll see an example where multiple items, like genres, are separated by commas in a single cell. These functions will help you break out those elements for better data loading. Let me know if that helps!
TigerGraph's Documentation: https://docs.tigergraph.com/gsql-ref/4.1/ddl-and-loading/creating-a-loading-job#_temp_table_and_flatten_functions

In an ideal situation, each of those three data elements in that "first" column would be broken out into their column.
